# Getting the property of an object via short circuit assignment

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `x` that could potentially be undefined. If it is, I wish to use another variable that I know is defined `y`. If `x` is defined, it has a property `a`. `y` always has the property `a`.

I want to get the value `x.a` if `x` is defined, otherwise I want to get the value `y.a`.

```
// x undefined 
y = { a: 0 };

console.log( (x || y).a )
```

I expect to see 0 printed to the screen, however, I get a `RefenceError: x is not defined`.

Comment: `typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x.a : y.a`.

Comment: you use strict mode it seems, the comment by @Tushar is correct

Comment: I was doing this using the node REPL. I assume that uses strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator for it:

```
var z = typeof x === 'undefined' ? y.a : x.a
```

Comment: One thing to note with this, is that it does not check if x.a is defined, only if x is

Comment: @Matthew that's fine - if x is defined I know that x.a is defined.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is not `undefined`, it doesn't exist at all. To make it work just add `var x;`, if `x` already exists it works as expected, if it doesn't it gets initialized to `undefined`.

```
 // x = { a: 1 }
 var x, y = { a: 0 };

console.log( (x || y).a );
```

PS: Actually `x` should always be defined (it might be `undefined` though), thats the actual problem in your code.

Comment: Ah - this is my mistake I thought anything that doesn't exist would be considered undefined. In reality I am using nested properties of an object (I simplified my problem to make it more succinct on here) and it seems as long as the underlying variable exists, any properties on it will be undefined.

Comment: @james yes, *property lookups* behave different than *variable lookups* ...

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
let result = x && x.a ? x.a : y.a
```

This is saying, if x.a is defined, set result as x.a, otherwise set it as y.a

Comment: One thing to note with this, is that it doesn't work if `x` isn't defined anywhere. Also, it doesn't work if `x.a` is either of `false`, `undefined`, `0`, `null` or `NaN`.

Comment: That is a good point, It's difficult to say what values are expected, but changes might need to be made depending on the expected type of `x.a`